# on AppFog, how to see the console logs on the terminal (node.js)

Tags: node.js, debugging, deployment, console, appfog

I would like to be able to see the console logs in my terminal  from my **node.js** App on **AppFog**. 
it it very hard to debug without it.

I saw something called tunnelling in the documentaion, is this what I'm looking for?
if so, could you explain me how to do it?

The screenshot below is from my local machine: how can I see a similar output from my AppFog instance?

[image: console logs on the terminal]

Edit:
*@Vadim* mention in his answer the command

```
af logs <your_app_name>
```

and it seems to work as expected, but it stops logging after few seconds,
how to tell it to keep watching?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can see console.log output via `af` tool. Type in console:

```
af logs <your_app_name>
```

Comment: it seems that it stop watching to logs after a few second, is there a way to keep it logging?

Comment: Unfortunately there is no way to keep logging for now. `af logs <appname>` just read last logs (or all logs with `--all` option) and exit. Like read from file.